# WMI Provider Host taking up half of CPU?

Tags: windows-8, wmi, provider

Recently, I have had something called WMI Provider Host in my Task Manager that is taking up about half of my cpu. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: does the activity go away after a reboot and come back later, or does it start as soon as the PC boots?

Comment: I think it comes on boot but ill check right now

Comment: Ok, I rebooted but it is not appearing but my user says its taking more pc than it is

Comment: its like saying its 20% on my user but cpu says i, taking like 90

Comment: Can you post screen shot, or a more detailed list?

Comment: follow the steps here: http://pastebin.com/v9Ct1RFr and give me the WMI xperf logging file.

Comment: ok and btw it started up ill take a screeny and stuff

Comment: how do i post screenshot

Comment: is there like, a way i could uninstall it?

Comment: Please run the xperf commands. this will tell me which process does WMI calls. But I need the trace.

Comment: @colin: Upload image to imgur.com and copy-paste link here.

Comment: @colin: any news? Have you done the xperf tracing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable WMI activity log in event log, (enable "show analytic and Debug log" in view option of event viewer), check which WMI query is running in Microsoft-Windows-WMI-Activity/Operational and trace log.
Or you can consider to rebuild wmi repository: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository/

Comment: Could you expand on how to rebuild the WMI repository?

Comment: The link I provided has a script to do that, but you can also manually rebuild it with 3 steps.  1: disable winmgmt service,   2. rename (backup) %windir%\system32\wbem folder  3. start winmgmt service.

Comment: More like *if* ms changes the link, that part of your answer becomes useless. So its always nice to have those sort of things in your answer, quoted or paraphrased appropriately.